# Is it wrong to edit badly formatted questions?

Tags: discussion, editing, formatting

I'm wondering if it's OK to edit questions that do not format or punctuate text well.

Comment: I've answered by example. It's fine to edit questions for poor presentation (or, as the case may be, to suggest such edits). But there are many questions here on Meta about editing questions and I'm voting to close yours as duplicate. If I'm missing the point and you have a new question please do tell us what it is.

Comment: @Nick, don't we have a better thread on editing? The one you found is very old and is quite poor. Perhaps this one is a better fit: [Editing Original Posts - Dos and Don'ts](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2810)? Your own answer there is very good.

Comment: @amoeba I was one person answering that one but I am happy to be told that it's better.